# Slider hover effect with bottom color strip not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I working on webpages containing tabs in which when hovering effect with slider is added but not working as expected here am attaching the code. when the mouse hovers over the slider has to transition ease 0.3s in the whole tab.

I want .container .slider{
position:relative;

but the blue slider getting hidden and also am not getting the hover effect

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
    background: #ff45
    
}

.container{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
        
}

.container ol{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
        
}

.container ol li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;    
    font-size: 25px;   
    
}

.container ol li b{
    color: #323232;
}

.container ol li:hover b{
    color: #007eff;
}

.container .slider{
    position:relative;
    height: 8px;
    width: 20%;
    background: #007eff;  
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BAsic HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ol>
            <div class="slider"></div>
            <li><b class="jee2">JEE Main Paper 2</b></li>
            <li><b class="nata">NATA - Maths</b></li>


        </ol>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want by adding your expected output?

Comment: https://ibb.co/qmcTrqQ  need a output like this

Comment: Oh so when you hover, you want the background color to be changed right?

Comment: no, i want the colour of text to change and a small 7px band of same colour as text to be showen below the text when it is hovered

Comment: what do you mean by 7px bank?

Comment: I thought you want the slider to move to the respective tab on hover.

Comment: sorry spelling error , if you see this image you can see a small color line below the text in the tab. I want this line to appear when hovered over the text

Comment: @Ava iwant slider to move to the respective tabs

Comment: Currently, the line is above the tabs. If I understand correctly, you want the blue line to appear underneath a tab whenever it is selected, and when a different tab is selected, the line should animate to it's new position - presumably both sliding and expanding(or contracting) to its new size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With double border:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
    background: #ff45
    
}

.container{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
        
}

.container ol{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.container ol li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;    
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li b{
    color: #323232;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li:hover b{
    color: #007eff;
}

.container ol li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #007eff;
    border-top-color: #007eff;
}

.container .slider{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 8px;
    width: 20%;
    background: #007eff;  
    transition: width 1s ease;
}

.container .slider li:hover {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <li><b class="jee2">JEE Main Paper 2</b></li>
    <li><b class="nata">NATA - Maths</b></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

### With animated slider:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
    background: #ff45
    
}

.container{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
        
}

.container ol{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.container ol li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;    
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li b{
    color: #323232;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li:hover b{
    color: #007eff;
}

.container ol li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #007eff;
    /*border-top-color: #007eff;*/
}

.container ol .slider{
    position: absolute;
    height: 7px;
    width: 0%;
    background: #007eff;  
    transition: width 1s ease;
}

.container ol li:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .slider {
    width: 50%;
}

.container ol li:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .slider {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li><b class="jee2">JEE Main Paper 2</b></li>
    <li><b class="nata">NATA - Maths</b></li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

### Automate using JavaScript:

Animate the slider for n-th child elements using JS.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var totalElements = elements.length;
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

elements.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    slider.style.width = `${(100 / totalElements) * (i + 1)}%`;
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    slider.style.width = '0%';
  });
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;    
    background: #ff45
    
}

.container{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
        
}

.container ol{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.container ol li{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;    
    font-size: 25px;
    border: 7px solid transparent;
    transition: border 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li b{
    color: #323232;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.container ol li:hover b{
    color: #007eff;
}

.container ol li:hover {
    border-bottom-color: #007eff;
    /*border-top-color: #007eff;*/
}

.container ol .slider{
    position: absolute;
    height: 7px;
    width: 0%;
    background: #007eff;  
    transition: width 1s ease;
}

/*.container ol li:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .slider {
    width: 50%;
}

.container ol li:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .slider {
    width: 100%;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li><b class="jee2">JEE Main Paper 2</b></li>
    <li><b class="nata">NATA - Maths</b></li>
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin for position and include hover code to see the change

```
.container .slider{
    position:relative;
    height: 8px;
    width: 20%;
    background: #007eff;
    margin:45px;

}

.container .slider:hover{
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

[image: sliderposition]